# Stop screen reader reading the href in <a>

Tags: html, hyperlink, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have anchor tag defined as below:

```
<a href="www.abc.com">
  <div tabindex="0" aria-label="XXXX"> 
   ...
  <div>
</a>
```

Currently, the screen reader reads the content of `href` in `<a>` tag. However, I don't want the `href` to be read, but the content in the `aria-label` in the `div`.

I would like to know what is the right way to achieve the goal?

Comment: what do you mean by "screen reader"? can you explain more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your <div> does not have any semantic meaning so the `aria-label` will essentially be ignored.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support.  Specifically, the third last bullet point:

> - Don't use aria-label or aria-labelledby on a <span> or <div> unless its given a role.

You do **not** want `tabindex="0"` on an element that is not actionable/interactive.

Just put your `aria-label` on the anchor itself:

```
<a href="www.abc.com" aria-label="XXXX">
```

Note that if there is any visible text in your anchor link (you have "..." in you sample code so I wasn't sure if there was any text there), make sure the `aria-label` contains that same text, plus any additional text that you want.  If you don't, then speech interface users may not be able to select your link.

Answer (score 0):

remove `aria-label` from the elements or you can use `aria-hidden="true"`

```
<a href="" aria-hidden="true">Screen reader cannot read me</a>
```

To know more about this check [here](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/)

Comment: The questioner isn't trying to hide the link from a screen reader. They are trying to announce the link by the intended name.

Answer (score -1):

Add the attribute `aria-hidden=“true”` to the `<a>` to hide it from screen readers. That will hide its child elements as well, so add `aria-hidden=“false”` to the `<div>` to un-hide it.

Comment: This will hide the link entirely from assistive technology, which isn't what the questioner asked for. The question was how to announce the link as the aria-label ("XXXX") instead of the content of the href attribute ("www.abc.com"). They weren't trying to hide the link, but convey it's intended name.